# Can the union of two disjoint arc connected spaces be arc connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

I was wondering if the union of two disjoint arc connected spaces can be arc connected arc connected but i can't seem to find a proof or simply an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$[0,1]$ and $(1,2]$ are arc connected and disjoint. Its union is $[0,2]$, also arc connected.

Comment: I don't get why ]1,2] is arc connected, i get why it's connected but not arcwise. could you explain it please?

Comment: Any two points $a,b\in[0,1]$ are conneccted by a continuous arc totally contained in $[0,1]$, namely the segment joining $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Yes $[0,1]$ is arc connected but why is the second interval that you mention $]1,2] $?

Comment: Exactly by the same reason.